# How to get full rows from core_config_data table?

Tags: database, mysql, core-config-data

I need to get the complete row from core_config_data table, to then make a few conditions. I know you can get a table by table-name, like:

```
->getTableName('table_name');
```

But i need to know if there's a way to call directly `core_config_data` table.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the `core_config_data` table's resource model:

```
Mage::getModel('core/config_data')->load($id)
```

You can even get the model from the collection, like any other collection in Magento:

```
Mage::getModel('core/config_data')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('config_id',$id);
```

Or just get the first item in the collection:

```
Mage::getModel('core/config_data')->getCollection()->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume the id parameter in ->load($id) is the scope_id value in core_config_data table, right?. If so, how can i get the scope_id value?

Comment: It is the config_id in the table, yes.

Comment: You can also use any other field name in `addFieldToFilter`, too.